# Using an array of search terms to search string in Excel

Tags: search, excel-formula

I have a named ranged called streetTypes which coinsidentally contain a list of different street types eg street, road, rd, lane, drive, cres etc.

What would like to do is search a string for a match and display the starting position of the match - NOTE not just a boolean response.

Using the formula the below formula in col H (streetTypes named range in column J) the following result is displayed.

```
=SEARCH(streetTypes,G2)
```

[image]

While I am aware of why it is bugging out, I am unsure of how to fix.

Help anyone??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `=MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(streetTypes,G2),""))` entered as an array formula (instead of hitting enter after typing the formula, type ctrl-shift-enter).

Use "Evaluate formula" (Formulas tab) to see how it works, but you'll get an array of numeric results or empty strings (one number for each term found) and then take the maximum to return the result found starting latest in your string. You could take the minimum to get the first in the string, but you probably want "Ave", not "st", in "53 **West** Seaside **Ave**".

Comment: Great tip on using the min/max function. I ended up with the formula `{=SEARCH(INDEX(streetTypes,MATCH(1,IF(SEARCH(streetTypes,G2),1,0),0)),G2)}` which did the same job, just with way more code. To solve the max/min issue by preventing it form finding sub-strings, I abbreviations things like st, rd, ave pl at the **end** of the streetTypes array, with avenue, place, street, road at the **beginning**. (Because it matches on the first occurance)... Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, that's a better plan. You might also be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481175/general-purpose-udfs-for-using-regular-expressions-in-excel

Comment: Oooohh. Very cool. You reckon it can be jigged to work with ranges? Ps:Thanks for your help. Just saw that you answered another one of my questions the other week :)

Comment: Actually, on closer examination, RXCount can be reworked by taking in a range, looping through it and converting it to a string. As for the other functions you have, I can see any really practical use for chucking ranges into them... Anyway... :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this cannot be done in excel as search function looks only for values in cells, not in a range. I have no knowledge of another such function which fulfills your needs.

Nevertheless, I suggest 2 solutions:

1- expand your "street type" range across columns, use them as headers and create a table. Use SEARCH function to get the starting positions of each street type. Use IFERROR function to return 0 instead of N/A, finally on the last column you can use the MIN function the get the lowest starting match position in a that row.

2- create a custom function with macros to loop through your street type range to find that value

good luck with both,

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but see above answer.